# Adding MVC 5 Identity to an Existing Project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am a novice programmer, learning as I work on my first code project. I started with MVC 4 and managed to get CRUD working for a single entity. I decided to try to tackle security next. When Visual Studio scaffolded my MVC 4 project, it added an account model, views, and controller. I have since upgraded my project to MVC 5 and EF 6 using [the procedure described here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2). I now want to replace the MVC 4 security code with MVC 5 scaffolded Identity model, view, controller.
Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: If you have no people actually using your site, I would just create a new MVC 5 project and copy over the new AccountController stuff.

Comment: I agree with @Jim Hill. However, you could try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/19940600/1210574 but even then I am not sure if Identity is compatible with MVC 4.

Comment: I agree with @vidalsasoon - if you are just starting to learn, you do not want to learn by making a new framework work with an old framework - you will hate it. Instead bring your single entity over to your MVC 5 project and go from there. I thought about answering this post but I just don't have the time to do all the research and work it will require.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ironically, I was just dealing with this issue a few nights ago...

I would suggest just going to an entirely new MVC 5 application. That being said, I'm not sure how far your application is in development.

What are you using for security right now? I'm going to assume SimpleMembership? If you did, there's a really nice article/project by [@Kevin Junghans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1090406/kevin-junghans) that involves [decoupling simplemembership from your application](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.ca/2013/03/decoupling-simplemembership-from-your.html).

You could theoretically, using that, get away with [decoupling simplemembership](https://simplesecurity.codeplex.com/), then using the answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19283944/1118488) add in identity.

My experience led me to redo-ing it, but again, I'm not sure how far you are in development, so I don't know if that is a viable option or not. If it is, I would just suggest that, and adding in your controllers as you go.

Comment: To add to @Dylan's answer I have now written a new article specific ASP.NET Identity, which is the new membership system used in MVC 5. It is called "Decoupling ASP.NET Identify From Your MVC 5 Application" [http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/11/decoupling-aspnet-identify-from-your.html]. I have written a new version of SimpleSecurity [http://simplesecurity.codeplex.com/] which uses ASP.NET Identity.  This basically has the same API as SimpleMembership to make it easy to plug into application originally developed using MVC 4 that are upgraded to MVC 5.

Comment: @Dylan, I started the project as MVC 4, so it contained the standard membership for MVC 4. I never implemented it in my software, nor did I ever even register a user simply because this is my first code project, and I wasn't ready to tackle it. When I heard that MVC 5 had a new version I wanted to be sure to upgrade before starting on this part of my code. I was far enough along that I found it too difficult to start from a new project. I ended up creating a separate MVC 5 project, and copying the membership pieces into my old project. It was painful, but a good learning experience.

Comment: Ah ok. Sounds a bit painful, but i mean, If you were doing this project to learn, and you learned more about the membership process in the end, then I guess it was worth it :)

Comment: Jim I'm looking to do the same. I have downloaded Visual Studio 2103 Express so that I can get the full mvc web application project files. I have an existing MVC 4 application I have updated to MVC 5. Now I need to upgrade all the Identity & membership stuff. Any info you can give on this? YOu think you could do an answer with the pain points etc?? I will Def upvote it if you do.