# asp.net roles management

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my Application I have three types of users.(1)anonymous user (2) Members and (3) Admin.

I want to create roles for these users: when a user want to visit the site then he/she may  see different Menus like an access control list. And when the user want to access the page or perform some sort of operation, then first its role is checked.

Suppose only admin can have the delete Operation access, so other users cannot see the delete operation or if this is not possible then at least he/she cannot allowed to do this operation.

I used   WSAT (website administration tool ) for asp.net application ,but later on I came to know that this not a good technique for production server to manage roles and user.
So I want a handsome technique to manage my application users.

Anybody please help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this MVC?
If so, have a look at ASP.NET Identity: http://www.asp.net/identity

Comment: Identity should work with aspx, too - but I have never used that

Comment: This is for visual studio 2013 , in my case visual studio 2012

Comment: I can get to work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19237285/using-asp-net-identity-in-mvc-4

If not, have a look at SimpleMembership, the predecessor of Identity.
Alternativly, there is https://github.com/brockallen/BrockAllen.MembershipReboot - an completely alternative approach

Comment: thank you @Christian Sauer I think it will work fine for me , and will help others too .I am marking it an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Also check out the new Thinktecture Identity Manager, which is meant as a better replacement for the WSAT tool.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ThinktectureIdentityManagerAsAReplacementForTheASPNETWebSiteAdministrationTool.aspx

Comment: @ Christian do you think all these are working on production server . or we could use this only in visual studio. what will be if i want to move my application to production server.?

Comment: I cannot comment on this tool, but all Membership solutions are fully production capablr