# How to accomplish admin only access to certain views(MVC4 Razor ) in a simple and effective way?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Sorry in advance if the question is already asked.

I have 2 users in my project and one of them is Admin.I want to **prevent the normal user entering** into admin's view pages in any manner. I am a newbie at MVC.

Help me with an explained answer if possible .

Comment: Try to use asp.net identity,You can define roles on it and its best way, otherwise you can use sessions in your application(my suggestion is never to use it)

Comment: would they support on mvc4?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19237285/using-asp-net-identity-in-mvc-4

Comment: Thanks,But i have doubt.Can i use this without entity framework in my project??

Comment: You mean you are using pageModels?if your answer is yes check https://www.learnrazorpages.com/identity