# Why isn't Roles attribute in Authorize is not working (MVC4 Razor)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have added everything which i needed for this,But still its is not working 
(am first time with Identity)

Here is my code:

> Controller

```
  [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public class AdminController : Controller
    {
     //Codes in the controller
```

}

> MyRoleProvider

```
  public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
        {
         var result=adminService.LoginData();//which has Role,and other datas
         string a=result.Where(x=>x.UserName==username).FirstOrDefault().Role;
         string[] output={a};
         return output;

        }
```

> Web.Config

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MyProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="MyProvider" type="bombays.MyRoleProvider"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
```

Login like this

```
 public ActionResult Login(Login log)
        {
            var p = adminService.adminLogin(log);

            if (p.UserName == log.UserName && p.Password == log.Password)
            {
                Session["adminusername"] = p.UserName;
                Session["adminname"]=p.name;
            }
            return View("AdminHome");
        }
```

I have checked lot of example but nothing saves me.
Now what is happening is ;Any user can view the page.Its *not even calling* **GetRolesForUser** function(tried with breakpoint)

Comment: What part of this isn't working? Be more specific.

Comment: Its not even calling GetRolesForUser function

Comment: I don't see you calling it anywhere in your code. Where are you setting the attribute?

Comment: Oops.Sorry just updated the question

Comment: Like most comments are saying you need to make the call to GetRolesForUser somewhere.  What type of authentication are you using?

Comment: Direct me to the blog post you used to implement this please.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19237285/using-asp-net-identity-in-mvc-4

Comment: also a tutorial video referenced from YouTube .I have installed those3 packages in my project then the code which i have tried

Comment: You're not calling the function anywhere. Also, Are you talking about `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core`? Why did you install that package for asp.net mvc 4? Edit your question and lay out all the steps you took. `step 1 ...` then I did `step 2...` Because right now we can't help you, this code isn't enough for me to see what's wrong.

Comment: Can you help me how to solve this in another way?